# translation-not-found to show internationalization data in the html template using generator jhipster

Tags: angular, internationalization, jhipster

I am using generator-jhipster to develop the application. but i18n will not show

error : translation-not-found[error.title]

[image]

blow is my code :

**.yo-rc.json**

```
{
    "generator-jhipster": {
        "promptValues": {
            "packageName": "com.myApp.app"
        },
        "jhipsterVersion": "4.5.1",
        "baseName": "myapp",
        "packageName": "com.myapp.app",
        "packageFolder": "com/myapp/app",
        .......,
        "clientFramework": "angularX",
        "useSass": true,
        "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
        "applicationType": "gateway",
        "testFrameworks": [],
        "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
        "enableTranslation": true,
        "skipServer": true,
        "languages": [
            "en"
        ]
    }
}
```

**error.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 jhiTranslate="error.title">Error Page!</h1>

        <div [hidden]="!errorMessage">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{errorMessage}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="!error403" class="alert alert-danger" jhiTranslate="error.403">You are not authorized to access the page.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The error.json file contain following location : src => main => webapp => i18n => en => error.json

**error.json**

```
{
    "error": {
        "title": "Error page!",
        "403": "You are not authorized to access the page."
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no error in browser console and am using generator-jhipster version 4.5.1

Comment: 4.5.1 is 17 releases behind current, any reason why you couldn't upgrade? translation-not-found error message is set in JhiMissingTranslationHandler class, by putting a breakpoint here you could get more information about where the problem is.

Comment: I have customized the jhipster generator locally using npm link so I didn't upgrade it because if I upgraded it I should have to do it from scratch again

Comment: 4.5.1 has ng2-translate and latest version4.10.2 has ngx-translate which is better and can we use ng2translate to localize.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're on your own here. When you can, it's always better to either build a module or submit your changes as pull requests.